# Get number of binary variables / Gurobi output in Drake

Tags: drake

How do I get the number of binary variables to my mathematical program?

How do I get a reference to a vector of all the aggregate binary variables?

Also, how do I get the Gurobi std output (this could also tell the number of binary variables)? Example here: [How to get how many binary variables used by Gurobi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826732/how-to-get-how-many-binary-variables-used-by-gurobi)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to loop through the variables and check which are binary:

```
from pydrake.solvers import MathematicalProgram
from pydrake.symbolic import Variable

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2)
b = prog.NewBinaryVariables(3)

binaries = [
    x for x in prog.decision_variables() if x.get_type() == Variable.Type.BINARY
]
print(len(binaries))
```